# Ajax request return empty data string but first got correct data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

Let's get on situation

I had a free domain but it was closed with no reasons by the webadmins. In that domain everything worked out perfectly but when I opened a new one in another site I began experiencing a weird behaviour.

The said behaviour consists of one request working perfectly but the other one doesn't.

Neither PHP nor javascript seem to be incorrect since when I print the response just before it gets encoded, it shows the correct data, but when it reaches the echo, it just sends data:""

[Result of printObject($json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpgoE.png)

What creeps me the most, is the fact that just before sendind it, the info is perfect

What could be causing it? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post some code. We can't really do anything without code.

Comment: 1. DO NOT POST IMAGES OF ANYTHING CODE-RELATED. EVER. POST THE ACTUAL TEXT. 2. Post your code! We can't help without code. 3. The "webadmins" almost certainly had a reason. Generally, it's "you weren't using it" or "we were running out of space for actual paying customers"; these kinds of "always free domain" things are always limited somehow.

Comment: QPaysTaxes, in reference to the webadmin, I simply mean that they have given me no reasons, I didn't want to say it wasn't legitim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved thanks to a friend of mine. As I thought, It wasn't a problem in the PHP code or the javascript code, it was a domain change matter. It was simply the version of php, which was different due to the domain change.

Thanks for the concern anyway

Answer (score 0):

May you please comment out the

```
     die;
```

in your code. After doing that you should now get something from the

```
   echo json_encode($json;
```

If that fails put more content on your question. Like the ajax function you are using and even php file names or functions you are calling.